# ggplot2 show separate mean values in box plot for grouped data

Tags: r, mean, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to create a box plot for grouped data that shows the mean of each group as a point in the box. Using the following code, I only get a single point for the two groups.

```
df <- data.frame(a=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")), 
    b=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.3), label=c("young","old")),
    c=rnorm(100))
ggplot(aes(y = c, x = b, fill = a), data = df) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=21, size=5, fill="white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the problem was changing the fill of the point, since the fill is the property that determines that two box plots of different color should be drawn, the point behaves as if there were only one group again. I think this should give you what you want.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=b, y=c, fill=a)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", size=5,
    position=position_dodge(width=0.75), color="white")
```

[image: box plot with mean]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this.

First, you could create a dummy data set which will contain the means per `a` per `b` using `aggregate`
Then, parse it into `geom_point` and add `position_dodge(width=.75)` that seem to match the default `dodge` in `geom_boxplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")), 
                 b=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.3), label=c("young","old")),
                 c=rnorm(100))

means <- aggregate(c ~ a + b, df, mean)

ggplot(aes(y = c, x = b, fill = a), data = df) + 
geom_boxplot() +
geom_point(data = means, aes(y = c, x = b), position=position_dodge(width=.75), color = "white")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I think the below solution is simpler.

Comment: I'll keep it for now as another option.